# How to force setting a certain member value when want to serialize for soap

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I have this method:

```
[WebMethod]
public OpenAccountResult OpenAccount()
{
    OpenAccountResult test = new OpenAccountResult(/*true*/)//the true  here wont let the object to be serialized
    {
        //Success = true,
        AccountNumber = "test111"
    };
    return test;
}
```

`OpenAccountResult` is actually extending `BaseSoapAnswer`, so I made `BaseSoapAnswer` constructor with one `bool` parameter for `Success`,  but I got an exception that an object with constructor that needs a parameter cannot be serialized.

Exception:

```
[InvalidOperationException: WebService.Services.TradingSystem.OpenAccountResult cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor.]
```

How do I force every `*Result` instance to declare `bool` `Success`.
I want to do it by implementing or inheriting because it there are going to be a lot of `*Result` and I don't want any other programmer to forget about it.

In the bottom line, I want to build the *Result in the way that every instance will have to set the Success, and if it is forgotten, the code would not be compiled, for safety reasons (You probably understand that if I would not need to be serialized I would not have a problem).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an additional parameterless constructor and mark it as Obsolete("only for serialization", true).
This will allow the compiler to use the constructor, but your user code will not compile when you are trying to use this constructor, even with inheritance:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }

    [Obsolete("only for serialization", true)]
    public MyBaseClass(){}

    public MyBaseClass(bool success) { this.Success = success; }
}

public class MyConcreteClass
{
    [Obsolete("only for serialization", true)]
    public MyConcreteClass() : base() {}

    public MyBaseClass(bool success) : base(success) { /* whatever in this instance */ }
}
```

you can even leave out the base constructor:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }

    public MyBaseClass(bool success) { this.Success = success; }
}

public class MyConcreteClass
{
    [Obsolete("only for serialization", true)]
    /* calling base constructor with false success parameter */
    public MyConcreteClass() : base(false) {}

    public MyBaseClass(bool success) : base(success) { /* whatever in this instance */ }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a parameter-less constructor in order to be serialized. But you want every `Result` to have `Success = true`?

```
public OpenAccountResult()
{
    Success = true;
}
```

Or if it's not *always* true and you want to specify `Success`, then you can simply have two constructors:

```
// required for serialization
public OpenAccountResult()
{
}

// alternate constructor for you to use
public OpenAccountResult(bool successValue)
{
    Success = successValue;
}
```

If you don't want to set every `Result` constructor, then do it in the base class. If the base class doesn't have a `Success` property, then make a subclass from which all your result classes can derive:

```
public abstract class Result : BaseSoapAnswer
{
    public Result()
    {
        this.Success = true;
    }

    public bool Success { get; set; }
}

public class OpenAccountResult : Result 
// ...
public class AnotherResult : Result
```

Comment: For your question yes. but your answer does not so much help me because I am going to have 50 `*Result` classes ans each must declare  `Success` , I need to inherit or implement because this is something that can be forgotten, in case of a single class I would agree, but not 50 classes, I have to provide better solution, thanks for your time

Comment: You need to better describe your problem. Does the `BaseSoapAnswer` have a `Success` property? Maybe you need to rethink your object hierarchy.

Comment: In the bottom line, I want to build the *Result in the way that every one will have to set the Success, and if it is forgotten, the code would not be compiled

Comment: My question was "Do you want every Result to have `Success = true`" - you replied "For your question yes".